# sql UNION breaks query

Tags: mysql, sql, union, left-join

Query :

```
            (
                SELECT
                    upd.uid,
                    upd.update_id,
                    upd.update,
                    upd.date,
                    upd.type,
                    upd.total_likes,
                    upd.total_comments,
                    upd.deleted,
                    usr.username AS `username`,
                    usr.profile_picture AS `profile_picture`
                    ,(
                        SELECT
                            COUNT(lik.id)
                        FROM
                            likes as lik
                        WHERE
                            upd.update_id = lik.item_id
                            AND
                            lik.uid = 118697835834
                            AND lik.type=0
                    ) as liked_update,
                    (
                        SELECT
                            COUNT(fav.id)
                        FROM
                            favorites as fav
                        WHERE
                            upd.update_id = fav.item_id
                            AND
                            fav.uid = 118697835834
                            AND fav.type=0
                    ) as favorited_update

                FROM 
                    updates AS upd
                    LEFT JOIN 
                        users AS usr
                            ON upd.uid = usr.uid
                WHERE
                    upd.deleted=0
                  AND
                    (
                        upd.uid=118697835834
                           OR EXISTS
                          (
                              SELECT *
                            FROM
                                subscribers AS sub
                            WHERE
                                upd.uid = sub.suid
                                  AND sub.uid = 118697835834
                          )
                    )

            )
            UNION
            (
                SELECT
                    topic.uid,
                    topic.tid,
                    topic.title,
                    topic.body,
                    topic.total_likes,
                    topic.total_replies,
                    topic.views,
                    topic.date,
                    usr.username AS `username`,
                    usr.profile_picture AS `profile_picture`
                    ,(
                        SELECT
                            COUNT(lik.id)
                        FROM
                            likes as lik
                        WHERE
                            topic.update_id = lik.item_id
                            AND
                            lik.uid = 118697835834
                            AND lik.type=1
                    ) as liked_update,
                    (
                        SELECT
                            COUNT(fav.id)
                        FROM
                            favorites as fav
                        WHERE
                            topic.update_id = fav.item_id
                            AND
                            fav.uid = 118697835834
                            AND fav.type=1
                    ) as favorited_update

                FROM 
                    topics AS topic
                    LEFT JOIN 
                        users AS usr
                            ON topic.uid = usr.uid
                WHERE
                    topic.deleted=0
                  AND
                    (
                        topic.uid=118697835834
                           OR EXISTS
                          (
                              SELECT *
                            FROM
                                subscribers AS sub
                            WHERE
                                topic.uid = sub.suid
                                  AND sub.uid = 118697835834
                          )
                    )

            )
            ORDER BY date DESC
```

I have added the `UNION ( SELECT )` and the query takes forever to load and finally it stops returning a `blank page`...

removing `UNION ( SELECT )` works fine...

Comment: Firstly why do you use a shortened alias for every column? It just makes it more difficult to read. Anyway what is the idea of the final EXISTS clause? You are using a union between updates and topics, but only selecting topics based on updates. The updates and topics will be on seperate rows in the result set so doing an exists on updates when you are not selecting from updates is probably a bad idea. There are probably a huge amount of recusrive loops being performed by the engine.

Comment: i can probably change the EXISTS clause to a LEFT JOIN...EDIT: i just removed all shortened alias and it seems to load but it doesnt load the topics... just updates...

Comment: Should the `WHERE`clause in that `EXISTS`be `topic.uid = sub.uid AND sub.uid = 118697835834`instead of `upd.uid = sub.suid AND sub.uid = 118697835834`

Comment: @Tobsey corrected typo, was my fault

Comment: Do the two select statements return data if run seperately? Also have you tried using `UNION ALL`instead of `UNION`. The latter removes duplicate records and therefore is slower. I don't think your statements could ever produce duplicates.

Comment: running them separate works, i also added `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` but still im only getting data from first `( SELECT )`

Comment: Sorry I'm out. Can't see anything wrong with the query as is and without a sample schema and data I can't say much more

Comment: ok i got a bit further... it seems to work but why are data from the second `( SELECT )` get stored in first `( SELECT )` columns instead of the second own columns?like title and body get stored on update and type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after all the comments can you please say what changes you made to get the script working.

In light of your comment about the data from two tables being in the same columns that is because you have told the engine to do that by using UNION. If you want them in seperate columns you will need to place Nulls in between:

```
SELECT
    upd.uid,
    upd.update_id,
    upd.update,
    upd.date,
    upd.type,
    upd.total_likes,
    upd.total_comments,
    upd.deleted,
    null AS `topicuid`,
    null AS `topictid`,
    null AS `topictitle`,
    null AS `topicbody`,
    null AS `topictotal_likes`,
    null AS `topictotal_replies`,
    null AS `topicviews`,
    null AS `topicdate`,
    usr.username AS `username`,
    usr.profile_picture AS `profile_picture`,
    (SELECT COUNT(lik.id) FROM likes as lik WHERE upd.update_id = lik.item_id AND lik.uid = 118697835834 AND lik.type=0) as liked_update,
    (SELECT COUNT(fav.id) FROM favorites as fav WHERE upd.update_id = fav.item_id AND fav.uid = 118697835834 AND fav.type=0) as favorited_update
FROM
    ......
UNION ALL
SELECT
    null AS `upd.uid`,
    null AS `upd.update_id`,
    null AS `upd.update`,
    null AS `upd.date`,
    null AS `upd.type`,
    null AS `upd.total_likes`,
    null AS `upd.total_comments`,
    null AS `upd.deleted`,
    topic.uid,
    topic.tid,
    topic.title,
    topic.body,
    topic.total_likes,
    topic.total_replies,
    topic.views,
    topic.date,
    usr.username AS `username`,
    usr.profile_picture AS `profile_picture`,
    (SELECT COUNT(lik.id) FROM likes as lik WHERE topic.update_id = lik.item_id AND lik.uid = 118697835834 AND lik.type=1) as liked_update,
    (SELECT COUNT(fav.id) FROM favorites as fav WHERE topic.update_id = fav.item_id AND fav.uid = 118697835834 AND fav.type=1) as favorited_update
```

You might need to do a bit more work on the column names but you should get there. You should read up on what the UNION operator actually does to two or more queries.

Comment: had to play around with the nulls to get them right but this is what i needed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you use UNION you have to have exact same results "column format, names,..." so you have at top of query upd.total_comments as `total_comments`, and bottom you have topic.total_replies as `total_replies` those are different names. hope you understand what i try to explain, if not visit [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/union.php) where it explains better.

Comment: got it, so i can rename the total_replies to total_comments but it will give me total_replies in data...

Comment: you can change the name in second(unioned) select by giving it alias name as you did topic.total_replies as total_replies just u have to name it total_comments as in first select. but formats must be also same or you have to transform them so if the field is bigint then in other must be bigint also.

Comment: "you have to have exact same results "column format, names,..." -- The requirement in standard SQL only requires the columns to be of the same types based on column ordering and does not compare column names (unless the `CORRESPONDING` keyword is used). I am not aware that mySQL relies on column names for `UNION`.